# Executar um job Spring Batch diversas vezes

Tags: java, spring, batch

Por padrão, o Spring Batch não permite executar um job que já possua uma execução completa com os mesmos parâmetros informados. Se você tentar executar, recebe a mensagem:

"A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={baz=quix, foo=bar}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters."

O problema é que preciso executar o mesmo batch diversas vezes ao dia, pensando nisso, utilizei o `incrementer` citado na documentação oficial:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {
  @Autowired
  private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
  @Autowired
  private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  @Bean
  public Job job() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory
      .get("jobRestService1").incrementer(
        new RunIdIncrementer()
      )
      .start(step1()).build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step step1() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory
      .get("step1").tasklet((stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
        System.out.println("Step1 ran today!");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }).build();
  }
}
```

O que ele faz é gerar um parâmetro `run.id` automaticamente. É como se você estivesse passando parâmetros diferentes para permitir a reexecução. Se eu executar o job diretamente, funciona, ele gera de fato o `run.id` e permite a reexecução. O problema é quando eu tento executar ele com um JobLauncher:

```
@RestController
public class JobLaunchingController {
  @Autowired
  private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @PostMapping(path = "/run")
  public ExitStatus runJob(@RequestBody JobLaunchRequest request) throws Exception {
    Job job = this.context.getBean(request.getName(), Job.class);
    return this.jobLauncher.run(job, request.getJobParameters()).getExitStatus();
  }
}
```

Ele ignora o `incrementer` e utiliza apenas os parâmetros que eu passei para o *run*.

Como eu faço para ele invocar o `incrementer` quando eu executar o job com o JobLauncher? Eu não quero ter que criar o parâmetro *run.id* na mão, já que eu configurei o job para criar isso pra mim através do `incrementer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para invocar o `incrementer`, é necessário apenas chamar o `getNextJobParameters`. Para isso, é necessário também injetar o `jobExplorer`. Ficaria assim:

```
@RestController
public class JobLaunchingController {
  @Autowired
  private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
  @Autowired
  private JobExplorer jobExplorer;
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @PostMapping(path = "/run")
  public ExitStatus runJob(@RequestBody JobLaunchRequest request) throws Exception {
    Job job = this.context.getBean(request.getName(), Job.class);

    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder(request.getJobParameters(), this.jobExplorer).getNextJobParameters(job)
        .toJobParameters();

    return this.jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters).getExitStatus();
  }
}
```

Os parâmetros são construídos pelo `JobParameterBuilder` de acordo com o que foi passado na requisição e no `jobExplorer`, que vai gerar o parâmetro de incremento configurado no job através da invocação do `getNextJobParameters`.